# How do I generate a matrix with random numbers from 1-9, with random rows and columns in PYTHON

Tags: python

This is my code, and it's not printing anything. Help, please.

```
import random

row=random.randrange(5,9)
col=random.randrange(5,9)
def matrix(row, col):
    c=[]
    for i in range (row):
        temp=[[],[]]
        for j in range (col):
            a=random.randrange(1,9)
            temp.append(a)
        c.append(temp)

    for square in c:
        print square
```

Comment: Did you invoke the function yet?

Comment: No, how do I do that? :(

Comment: you need to call matrix function `matrix(row,col)` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import random

row=random.randrange(5,9)
col=random.randrange(5,9)
def matrix(row, col):
   return [[random.randrange(1,9) for a in range(row)] for b in range(col)]

print matrix(row,col)
```

Comment: Okay, okay. That's what my friend told me, but I don't know how. :)) I'll try it. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: i'm not sure if this is the kind of matrix you are looking for, i suppose by the transcript that rows are integers not lists, if the rows should be lists change the randrange part to create lists

Comment: Yeah, the output doesn't look like a matrix, but at least that, I know how to alter. :) Thank you. :)

Comment: could you please mar answer as valid if it worked for you? it may help other users in the future if they have similar problems, thanks